# Android mock object show NPE on when new object created inside method

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm new in testing and have a problem with a mock object. When I pass the call method that doesn't require any value the test is successful. But when I pass the value to the method and put it to JsonObject I have NPE. Why passed the argument to JsonObject lead to an error?

**Class I want to test:**

```
open class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val movieApi: MovieApi
) : UserRepository {

override suspend fun createSession(requestToken: String): String {
    val body = JsonObject().apply {
        addProperty("request_token", requestToken) // error happen when I put argument to JsonObject
    }
    return movieApi.createSession(body = body) // NPE 
        .await()
        .body()
        ?.getAsJsonPrimitive("session_id")
        ?.asString ?: ""
    }
}
```

**Test case:**

```
class UserRepositoryImplTest {

@get:Rule
val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

@Mock
lateinit var movieApi: MovieApi

@Mock
lateinit var localPrefStorage: LocalPrefStorage

lateinit var userRepository: UserRepositoryImpl

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    userRepository = UserRepositoryImpl(movieApi, localPrefStorage)
}

@Test
fun createSession() {
    runBlocking {
        val value = userRepository.createSession("request_token")
        assertEquals(value, "")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are mocking the movieApi and you should tell the mocked movieApi what to do if createSession method called

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
  userRepository = UserRepositoryImpl(movieApi, localPrefStorage)
  when(movieApi.createSession(body)).thenReturn(result)
}
```